# Error compiling ruby 1.9.3 on Solaris

Tags: c, ruby, compilation, compiler-errors

[image]

I am looking at this error. The architecture I'm compiling ruby on is Solaris-i386.

This ruby version compiles fine on my other box, ubuntu. i'm thinking, I am using a wrong compiler and/or incorrect options? Something was mentioned about c89 and c99 flags (-std=c99), can someone elaborate on exactly how those are supposed to be used when doing `./configure; make; make install`?

I read this somewhere: and it doesn't fix it, but I'd like to include it in the question as potentially helpful info

```
Solaris 8 requires #include <values.h> to get most of the system-dependent maths 
values, and even then it doesn't have HUGE_VAL, despite this being referenced in the 
math(3HEAD) man page.

By changing the reference to use MAXFLOAT instead and adding the #include above 
math.h, the code compiles - whether it achieves the same end is an interesting question...
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to enable 64bit architecture when configuring.

`CFLAGS=-m64 ./configure --prefix=/usr ...`